# Load JS only on specific content_type node creation

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-hooks

Drupal 6. What is the proper way to execute `drupal_add_js` only when specific `content_type` is being created?

I have some jQuery code that needs to execute only to control some form elements in a specific content_type creation.

I already have a module, which has a different name from the content_type. Is this a problem? Can I still hook onto the form? If so, what is the correct way to generate the hook to the specific `node/add/content_type`?

Edit: this is only needed for the creation, not the view.

Edit 2: code that's not working at the moment:
file: testmod.module

```
function testmod_form_node_type_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
   if ($form['#node_type']->type == 'testnode') {
     drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'testmod') . '/new_msg.js');
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably a few ways to do it but I'd use a `form_alter` hook:

```
function mymodule_form_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  if (!isset($form['#node']->nid) && $form['#node']->type == 'my-type') {
    drupal_add_js('my-file.js');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Clive. I am not sure why the hook isn't getting called. I've cleared cache, the module is definitely working (some custom pages it creates are displaying), and my JS file is valid (it is being used on another page with the same call). I'll update my post with the code. Thank you again.

Comment: @djdy: Sorry I misunderstood what you were trying to do, I've update the code in the answer it should work now

Comment: That didn't seem to read either... I ended up using _form_alter... Is that frowned upon?

Comment: Not at all, the one above is just [`hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/6) which is (supposed) to target the form specifically by ID. using the standard `hook_form_alter()` is just as valid a way to do this :)

Comment: Thank you for explaining this, Clive.